# Request dispatcher page not getting redirected when tested on hosting server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I placed some pages of my web application on server some days back. I uploaded first `index.jsp`, which is the home page of the application.
There is an anchor tag in index page like this:

```
<a href="Controller?name=Rohan">Name</a>
```

When I am clicking on the link, it's going to desired controller and there I have placed a `requestdispatcher` object to send it to next jsp page for viewing like below:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("New2.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Its not going to `New2.jsp` page. When I am testing whole thing on my hosting server. I'm clicking on anchor tag above and then its going to controller, but there its showing me whole code in the browser.
What should I change to redirect it to next `New2.jsp`. `New2.jsp` and `index.jsp` both are in my root folder only.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: try this `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/New2.jsp");`

Comment: no sir,it still the same.showing the code only..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone-Do i need to add any jar files for servlet in hosting server folder for this issue.or some other required file for this....

Comment: @user3488008 How is your `index.jsp` getting displayed . if your code is displayed in  browser . it seems you have not deployed the app in the app server

Comment: index.jsp is getting displayed properly as it is without any problem.on clicking only it goes to controller and shows the code in browser.what do i need to check in my root folder on server sir????

Comment: Anybody please help me what should i change in my request dispatcher url so tht it goes to next page.or do i need to upload any extra files,as this is first time i m loading a new web application

Comment: "its showing me whole code in the browser" the code in your controller is being displayed?

Comment: If the Java code of your controller is being displayed, then that sounds like the web server does not support running the Java application. What is the web server hoster?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss this statement in your controller

```
response.setContentType("text/html")
```